# How should I implement an Ajax Menu?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, menu

My ASP.NET MVC has the need for a vertical navigation menu where submenus would be generated dynamically via ajax when the user clicks on the parent menu item. I would like to use jQuery and Css to drive the menu but that's just a preference.

I really don't want to reinvent the wheel here. I know this type of menu has been done before. For example, [Deluxe Menu](http://deluxe-menu.com/ajax-technology-menu-sample.html) and [Telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/menu/examples/programming/webservice/defaultcs.aspx) (links are to their ajax menu demos) offer the functionality I'm after. Are there any free ajax menu plugins/samples available? How would you implement the menu?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the open source Telerik controls for MVC?

They are implemented very nicely, in pure MVC and use jQuery so are not bloated like some Webforms based products have been in the past.

Link: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The Telerik menus don't have built-in Ajax support like their Treeview control, but I'm sure I could hook it up if needed. I'll keep this in mind.